# datatable column expression error

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I am getting a syntax error " Missing operand after 'Price' operator" with the following code, which should be right but obviously isn't. Any thoughts on where the error is?

```
    table.Columns.Add("ADR Price", GetType(Double))
    table.Columns.Add("ORD Price", GetType(Double))
    table.Columns.Add("Currency Price", GetType(Double))
    Dim cDiff As DataColumn = New DataColumn
    With cDiff
        .DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Double")
        .ColumnName = "Difference"
        .Expression = "ADR Price - (ORD Price * Currency Price)"
    End With
    table.Columns.Add(cDiff)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm <strike>fairly</strike> sure that the exception is caused by your whitespaces in the column-names.

You should wrap the names in brackets or remove the spaces:

```
.Expression = "[ADR Price] - ([ORD Price] * [Currency Price])"
```

But then the next will probably walk into this trap. So in my opinion removing would be better:

```
.Expression = "ADR_Price - (ORD_Price * Currency_Price)"
```

Answer (score 0):

This error comes because of an apostrophe in the value ( ' ). Check if the price value is containing any apostrophe, if its containing any, just double it.

See this link: http://aspnetresources.com/blog/apostrophe_in_rowfilter